# How to add simple moving average to macd kind of indicator

Tags: pine-script

I have a indicator same like MACD I want to add SMA to it. But when I try to embed SMA code in MACD code it is not showing as MACD is range bound where as SMA can go between 0 to 1000's. Here as a workaround I am doing this way,,,enabling MA and move to EXISTING PANE BELOW. Kind of stuff. Could any one help us in achieving this

```
//
// @author LazyBear
//@version=2
//
// If you use this code in its original/modified form, do drop me a note. 
//
study(title="WaveTrend [LazyBear]", shorttitle="BUCKET")
n1 = input(10, "Channel Length")
n2 = input(21, "Average Length")
obLevel1 = input(60, "Over Bought Level 1")
obLevel2 = input(53, "Over Bought Level 2")
obLevel3 = input(40, "Over Bought Level 3")
osLevel1 = input(-60, "Over Sold Level 1")
osLevel2 = input(-53, "Over Sold Level 2")
osLevel3 = input(-40, "Over Sold Level 3")
 
ap = hlc3 
esa = ema(ap, n1)
d = ema(abs(ap - esa), n1)
ci = (ap - esa) / (0.015 * d)
tci = ema(ci, n2)
 
wt1 = tci
wt2 = sma(wt1,4)

plot(0, color=gray)
plot(obLevel1, color=red)
plot(osLevel1, color=green)
plot(obLevel2, color=red, style=3)
plot(obLevel3, color=red)
plot(osLevel2, color=green, style=3)
plot(osLevel3, color=green)

plot(wt1, color=green,title = 'GREEN')
plot(wt2, color=red, style=3)
plot(wt1-wt2, color=blue, style=area, transp=80)

// I am trying to embed sma but it is going in vain. Please help here

signal = sma(close, 9)
plot(signal, color=color.blue)
```

Comment: Your code won't compile since you are using `color.blue` on version 2 of pine script. On older versions, you need to use just `blue`. For example: `plot(signal, color=blue)`

Comment: that I will take care could you please help me on the question asked, how to add SMA

Comment: You already added the `sma`. If I understand you correctly, you are looking to add the `sma` and scale it to the range between the highest and lowest levels you've drawn? In your example, take the `sma`, and regardless of its true value, set a number between `obLevel1` and `osLevel1`?

Comment: Please edit and clarify your question, it is hard to help you this way.

Comment: @mr_statler could you please help me in coding that?? as suggested

Comment: See @G.Lebret answer above